# MongoDB deep search: findOne with slash in property name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Having trouble with hitting a document which contains a slash (/) in the property name.

Imagine this two documents in the collection _directories:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "fdgfd20ec493a00bc4897"
    },
    "folders": {
        "/home/pub": {
            "public": true
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "v1ddefdgd2c493a676jlg"
    },
    "folders": {
        "/home/pub": {
            "public": false
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to search for one of them:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('myUri', { useUnifiedTopology: true , useNewUrlParser: true })
.then(mongoClient => {

    const db = mongoClient.db('myDatabase');
    const collection = db.collection('_directories');

    collection.findOne({
        folders: {
            '/home/pub': {
                public: true
            },
        }
    }).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    });

}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried patterns like `folders['/home/pub']: { public: true }`.

Is it possible to query properties with a slash like `/home/pub/'`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something like: `\/yourword` or search by regexp for that?

Comment: Have you tried dotted notation like `{'folders./home/pub.public':true}`?

Comment: @AlexZeDim does not work.

Comment: @Joe dotted notation works. Thanks. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can just use the dot notation to navigate sub-properties

```js
> db.test.findOne({ "folders./home/pub.public": true})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f116ca28f807dc2dc98b6f3"),
        "folders" : {
                "/home/pub" : {
                        "public" : true
                }
        }
}
```